# In a Rails API, is there a standard way to "paginate" or "chunk" large API requests responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, api

Scenario:

- I have a Rails API with a `/tasks.json` endpoint that serves all the Tasks.
- For large Accounts this can sometimes be close to 1,000,000 records.
- Sending 1,000,000 records over the wire in JSON generally doesn't work due to a network timeout, etc.

I can easily "paginate" the number of tasks being sent so the endpoint uses something like `/tasks.json?limit=10000&page=1` but how does the client know to send this?

Is there a "standard" way to handle large requests like this and break them up naturally into chunks?

Does each client need to handle this on their end manually?

Thanks!

Comment: "but how does the client know to send this" - from your documentation, of course. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Haha. Yeah, if there's no computer-to-computer way to let the client know, that could be all there is to it. Do you return an error when the request is over a certain size and they have not included these request params? Is it useful to have an endpoint like `tasks/count` that tells them the total # of records?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-pagination

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, that helps a lot to standardize the response. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use kaminari gem. It handles all requests and paginates it. It works both on Rails Api apps and rails standard apps.
https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Comment: We actually do use this for everything but our API. It's fantastic. What I'm interested in is the Best Practice to use this in an API. How to inform the client of how many records there are and ensure they know how to paginate their requests appropriately.

Comment: [RFC 5988 defines](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) the `Link` header you can use to send over next/prev page URLs to the client. This way any client that is compatible with RFC 5988 will be able to use that information regardless of implementation details. See [GitHub's API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) as an example.